# Comparing two values from different input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, input

I tried to make a small input form as a small project. Here is the HTML from the two input fields:

```
Password:<br>
<input type="text" name="password" em-pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+])(?=.*[A-Z]).{4,}$" class="password">
<br>
Repeat password:<br>
<input type="text" name="rpassword" class = "rpassword">
<br>
```

Here is the code I wrote that compares the two values for each field:

```
$(".rpassword").on('blur', function(){
  var password = $(".password").val();
  var rpassword = $(".rpassword").val();
  console.log(password);
  console.log(rpassword);
  if(password !== rpassword){
      alert('Passwords do not match');
  }
});
```

Although the syntax is correct, it still returns an error upon reaching the if comparison. Anyone have any ideas why this might be happening? 
The password accepted is with upper cases, lower cases, numbers and special characters.

Comment: I don't see any problem [**`here`**](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/aoka9kw0/).

Comment: I am using jsbin to make the small project and there it does not work.

Comment: Here is the error that appears:    "error"
    "@reqacuduni.js:52:5
    jQuery.event.dispatch@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js:3073:15
    jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js:2750:6
    "

Comment: I've tested your code and it works properly.

Comment: have you loaded jquery in jsbin?

Comment: Yes. It is properly loaded. <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

Comment: I don't see any problem on [**`jsbin`**](https://jsbin.com/biqeso/edit?html,js,output) either.

Comment: That's the problem. It does not work in jsbin. That's the only place it does not work. I will try and put it through Sublime text now and see how it goes.

Comment: As shown (in the comments) there is nothing wrong with the code as entered in the question.  If there's some other issue, please update with specifics.  eg it appears it *only* doesn't work in jsbin, yet has been shown to work in jsbin - so it's entirely how you've setup jsbin which has nothing to do with the question as asked.

Comment: Indeed. It seems there is a problem on my side with jsbin. The code was good all along. I will try to fix the issue on my side. Thanks to everyone for the help.